# Is "unfounded" correct? Why?

Tags: grammar

Why is *unfounded* correct? Shouldn't it be just *unfound*? Why is there *-ed* added? Is it changing meaning?

In my understanding, I would use *unfound* to express something was not possible to find in past (or just now). But as *found* is past version of *find* I don't see reason why to add *-ed*.

Comment: Alas, logic does not apply to usage. *Unfounded* means without a basis (in other words, without logical or evidentiary foundation); *unfound* means searched for futilely (in other words, you couldn't find it). Just the way it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Found* is the infinitive form of a verb (from which *foundation* is derived):

> [**found**<sup>2</sup>](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/found#found_Verb_200)
>
> Establish or originate (an institution or organization)
>   Plan and begin the building of (a settlement)
>   Base (something) on a particular principle, idea, or feeling.
>   Serve as a basis for.
>
> [ODO]

Thus a building or a nation can be founded ("The First Republic of France was founded on 22 September 1792.") Moving the meaning only slightly, something which has no basis can be said to be *unfounded:*

> He expressed the unfounded belief that I was Martian.

Comment: So, *The company XY was unfounded because of lack of money* and *The searched text was unfound in the database*, is that correct?

Comment: No. *Founded* (pp of verb *to found*) and *found* (pp of *to find*) are not the same. *Unfounded* means *baseless,* not "not found", and not "not established". You can't just tack *un-* on a verb; I disagree with deadrat there.

Comment: I'm getting confused, if `unfounded` has completely different meaning from `founded`, what is the base of the `unfounded`? ... so it should be *The company XY wasn't found because of lack of money*. But what about the other sentence, how do I express there were no results using verb `*to* find`? Does a negated past form of word `find` exist?

Comment: No: *to found* (pp founded) and *to find* (pp found) are different, so if you want the sense "established", it's "The company XY wasn't founded because of lack of money." If you want the sense "located", it's "The company XY wasn't found because of lack of money." The word *unfound* is almost always wrong: the easy rule is not to use it because "not found" will always be right. But that's not the same as "not founded" or "unfounded", because *find* and *found* are different verbs, as different as "locate" and "establish".